# htaccess SetEnvIf Remote_Addr is in Ip Address range

Tags: regex, .htaccess

i want set a environmet variable in htaccess if the client ip address is in the range from 192.168.1.192 to 192.168.1.255.

this is my code

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^192\.168\.1\.(?:19[2-9]|2[0-5][0-9])$" FOO=BAR
```

this also validate 192.168.1.256, 192.168.1.257... how fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to see if this Regex does what you want it to do. It does not look pretty, but does the job:

```
192\.168\.1\.((19[2-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])?)
```